# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - What SQL file(s) to create USERSTORE_DB

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm installing WSO2IS 5.10.0 and I am creating five PostgreSQL databases per the column titled **Recommended Database Structure** in this document:

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/setup/setting-up-separate-databases-for-clustering/

Actually it's six databases if you count the CARBON_DB.   The five PostgreSQL databases are named as follows: SHARED_DB, USERSTORE_DB, IDENTITY_DB, CONSENT_MGT_DB and BPS_DB.  I already have them configured in the deployment.toml file.  I've created the databases in PostgreSQL and I have to manually execute the SQL files against each database in order to create the schema for each database.  Based on the document in the link, I have figured out which SQL files to execute for four of the databases.  However, I have no idea what SQL files I need to execute to create the USERSTORE_DB schema.  It's got to be one of the files under the dbscripts directory but I just don't know which one(s).  Can anybody help me on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CARBON_DB contains product-specific data. And by default that stores in the embedded h2 database. There is no requirement to point that DB to the PostgreSQL database. Hence you need to worry only about these databases  SHARED_DB, USERSTORE_DB, IDENTITY_DB, CONSENT_MGT_DB and BPS_DB.

As per your next question, You can find the DB scripts related to USER_DB(USERSTORE_DB) in /dbscripts/postgresql.sql file. This file has tables starting with the name ***UM_***.  These tables are the user management tables. You can use those table sql scripts to create tables in USERSTORE_DB.

Refer the following doc for more information

[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/administer/user-management-related-tables/

Comment: Thanks, I just used the same postgresql file to create both databases.  Both will have some extra tables in them but no harm.